# Link multiple cells from Excel to Word without inserting line break

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, hyperlink

I have a Word doc in which I'm inserting links to an Excel file. For single Excel cells I can use `Paste Special>Paste Link>Unformatted Text` to link to just the cell contents. However, sometimes I want to link multiple cells laid out as a table in Word.

If I copy the cell range I want and then use `Paste>Link & Use Destination Styles` or `Paste>Link & Keep Source Formatting`, a line break gets inserted above the table, which I do not want but can't get rid of as it's part of the linked field. If I use the unformatted text option, I lose the basic table layout. None of the `Paste Special` options seem to work for this.

The only workaround I can think of is to link as unformatted text each cell in the table individually, but with sometimes hundreds of cells, that's not really an option. Help! What can I do?

(One reason I am having trouble with the line break above is that I'm trying to use `Insert Caption` with the tables thus linked, but when I do, the resultant caption gets incorporated into the linked field, and so when I update fields, the caption disappears since it's not in Excel... workarounds for that would help too.)

I am using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.

Answer (score 0):

This is just one of those things:

[image]

Possible workaround:

```
Make the font size of the line break equal to one (just type it in the dropdown box, even though it stops at 8). I believe this should also solve you caption problem.
```